# Gibt es einen Passiv-Ersatzinfinitiv?

Tags: grammar, passive, perfect-tense

Gilt der Ersatzinfinitv auch im Passiv? Ich habe schon im Internet geschaut und kann die Antwort selbst nicht finden.

z.B.

> Der Wagen wurde nicht bewegen können.

Bedeutet das: „The car could not be moved“?

Comment: The sentence is wrong but most Germans would understand what you mean. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es gibt ihn, aber die Konstruktion wäre eine leicht andere:

> Der Wagen *hat* nicht bewegt *werden können.*